# Индксация по ключевому значению

Tags: c#, классы

Доброго времени суток. У меня появилась необходимость реализовать индексатор типа this["key"], который возвращал бы мне поля класса по ключевому слову "key". Сейчас это реализовано как

```
switch(key)
{
   case "Имя_поля":
       return Поле;
   ... 
}
```

Есть ли возможность перебора полей класса в цикле? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то надо сделать так:

```
PropertyInfo[] prop = richTextBox1.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo x in prop)
        {
            // Тут зависит от того, что вам надо вывести, значение поля или его имя
            richTextBox1.Text += x.Name + "\n"; // имя поля
            //richTextBox1.Text = x.ToString() + "\n"; //значение поля, если оно есть
        }
```

Comment: То что надо! Присного благодарен:)

Comment: А вот возвращение занчения x.ToString() не срабатывает. Есть еще идеи?

Comment: PropertyInfo[] prop = this.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo p in prop)
{
    if (key == p.Name)
    {
        return p.GetValue(this, null).ToString();
    }
}

Вот так работает

Comment: Хм, забавно, только что проверял с GetValue немного по другому, не работало )). Плюсанул к вопросу.